# Fix/improve if statement with foreach not null

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, null, switch-statement

Having this code:

```
$main = !empty($searchResults['main']) ? $searchResults['main'] : null;
$second = !empty($searchResults['second']) ? $searchResults['second'] : null;
$third = !empty($searchResults['third']) ? $searchResults['third'] : null;

#if(($main) || ($second) || ($third))
if((($main) || ($second) || ($third)) !== NULL)
{
    foreach ((array)$searchResults as $key => $value)
    {
        switch ($key)
        {
            case "main":
            ....
```

What can it be done to fix/improve this code?

By fix I mean that I need a way to avoid running switch on empty keys

Comment: remove all the empty keys/values in the $searchResults array, that way, you wont have empty keys to switch

Comment: switch inside a foreach is a crazy construction. Why do you need the foreach, since $searchResults is an one level depth array and you know the keys ?

Comment: I need the switch because each and one of the mentioned variables contained data in very different order and I need to filter that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($searchResults as $key => $value)
{
  if(empty($value)) continue;
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally just do

```
if(!empty($searchResults['main'])
{
    $main = $searchResults['main'];
    //do stuff
}

if(!empty($searchResults['second'])
{
    $second = $searchResults['second'];
    //do stuff
}
```

..etc.